# Can't open AVD manager, but can run the project with emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I updated some points in SDK Manager in Eclipse (mac). But today when I press Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager, it can't open and I get this message (I get this message when I launch Android SDK Manager too, but after I press OK, SDK Manager opens).

[image]

So the main problem is then I can't add/update Emulators. But when I build the project and run with emulator, everything is fine, so emulator is working, I just can't open AVD Manager.

Pls help me.

Comment: check the path to android sdk.

Comment: I'm new in android, can you help how to check this path?

Comment: Open Window > Preferences > Android
and set sdk path in SDK Location.

Comment: I just pressed Help - > check for updates (in Eclipse) and updated everything. That helped. But anyway thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pressed Help - > check for updates (in Eclipse) and updated everything. That helped.